# How does this code work in this specifics regarding async wait

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await

I learn some React and Redux and have a beginner question.

In the GitHub code below there are two method calls `getInitUsers()` and `getMoreUsers()`.
[Here is Original GitHub code for the below code](https://github.com/oluSammy/leadpreneur-admin/blob/master/src/pages/users-page/users-page.components.jsx)

```
....
useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
        await getInitUsers();
    }
    getUsers();
}, [getInitUsers]);

const addMoreUsers = () => {
    if(!isGettingMoreUsers) {
        getMoreUsers(prevDoc);
    }
}

....

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getInitUsers: () => dispatch(asyncGetInitUsers()),
    getMoreUsers: prevDoc => dispatch(asyncGetMoreUsers(prevDoc))
})

...
```

The Redux action for the above `getInitUsers()` and `getMoreUsers()` are this two:
[Here is the original GitHub code for the below code](https://github.com/oluSammy/leadpreneur-admin/blob/master/src/Redux/Users/users.actions.js)

```
export const asyncGetInitUsers = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            dispatch(getUsersStart());
            const usersRef = firestore.collection("users").orderBy("registrationDate", "desc").limit(30);
            usersRef.onSnapshot(docSnapShot => {
                let users = [];
                docSnapShot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    users.push({id: doc.id, data: doc.data()});
                });
                dispatch(getUsersSuccess(users));
                const lastDoc = docSnapShot.docs[docSnapShot.docs.length - 1];
                dispatch(setPrevDoc(lastDoc));
            });

        } catch (errorMsg) {
            dispatch(getUsersFailure(errorMsg));
        }
    }
}

export const asyncGetMoreUsers = prevDoc => {

    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            dispatch(getMoreUsersStart());

            const usersRef = firestore.collection("users").orderBy("registrationDate", "desc").startAfter(prevDoc).limit(30);
            usersRef.onSnapshot(docSnapShot => {
                let users = []
                docSnapShot.docs.forEach(doc =>{
                    users.push({id: doc.id, data: doc.data()})
                });
                dispatch(getMoreUsersSuccess(users));
                const lastDoc = docSnapShot.docs[docSnapShot.docs.length - 1];
                dispatch(setPrevDoc(lastDoc));
            });
        } catch (e) {
            dispatch(getMoreUsersFailure(e));
        }
    }
}
```

I understand placing the `getInitUsers()` in the `useEffect()` will make it run once on Component creation. What I want to ask is what does this `await` do on this line:

```
 await getInitUsers();
```

If you look at the `getMoreUsers()` it does not have the `await` and if you look at the two action `asyncGetInitUsers()` and `asyncGetMoreUsers()` abowe they have the same logic and starts with:

```
 return async dispatch => {...
```

So what is the difference here? `getInitUsers()` and `getMoreUsers()`??
I created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-async-wait-98g0j?file=/src/App.js) to try to understand the `await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `await` does nothing different, there's actually no point in using async await because you aren't doing anything after the await or returning a value from it.

So, the `getInitUsers` bit could be simplified to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getInitUsers();
}, [getInitUsers]);
```

For example, if you wanted to run some code after the getInitUsers finished. For example, a loading boolean:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);
  const getUsers = async () => {
    await getInitUsers();
    setLoading(false);
  };
  getUsers();
}, [getInitUsers]);
```

Though due to the simplicity of the code, this could be simplified by using promises directly:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);
  getInitUsers().then(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  });
}, [getInitUsers]);
```

---

For some documentation on async await and what it does for us: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await, but here's a bit of an intro:

Essentially, async/await is a combination of features that allow for easier asynchronous flows in JS.

> These features basically act as syntactic sugar on top of promises,
> making asynchronous code easier to write and to read afterwards. They
> make async code look more like old-school synchronous code, so they're
> well worth learning. This article gives you what you need to know.

`async` functions always return a promise, and they do so the moment they are called.
When the async function finishes execution, then that promise resolves to the value returned from it (undefined if nothing is returned) or is rejected with an error.

`await` only works in async functions (though there is a proposal that's in stage 3 for [Top Level Await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)). `await` takes a promise and waits for it to be resolved or rejected before continuing execution and unwrapping the promise.

So, without async/await, you need to use the `.then` or `.catch` functions of promises, but with async/await, you can do a lot to reduce callback hell.

Here's some very contrived examples to show how using the async/await syntatic sugar can make code easier to read and reason through. Though the biggest danger is also that async/await makes the code look synchronous even though it's not.

```js
// Setting up a couple promises
let promise = new Promise(resolve => resolve(42));
let promise2 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(8));

// Using promises to multiply them together
Promise.all([promise, promise2])
  .then(([value, value2]) => value * value2)
  .then(value => console.log('promises', value))


// Setting up a couple promises
let promise3 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(42));
let promise4 = new Promise(resolve => resolve(8));

// Using async/await to multiply them together
(async() => {
  let value = await promise3 * await promise4;
  console.log('async/await', value);
})()
```